# Extending a 2d plot to 3d

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

So having trouble making a plot of this potential in 3D

$\ U(x) = \frac{k^2}{4g} - \frac{k}{2}x^2 + \frac{k}{2}x^4$

This is what I have for 2D

setting `k = 1` and `g = 1`

```
U[x_] := .25 - .5 x^2 + .5 x^4

Plot[U[x], {x, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

How do I extend this to 3D with mathematica ?

Comment: What's the second variable besides $x$?

Comment: Not sure I need one as just extending the a simplified version of the higgs potential. The RevolutionPlot3D function does the job .

Comment: @corey979 forgot to tag you, do you know of another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RevolutionPlot3D[1/4 - x^2/2 + x^4/4, {x, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , that is exactly what I was looking for. I was not aware of RevoultionPlot3D .

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that you have a difference in a factor of $1/2$ in your $x^4$ term....